# ActiveSupport::Notifications should be async?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have an extremely simple setup that tests the rails3 `ActiveSupport::Notifications`.
By reading the documentation, the `ActiveSupport::Notifications.subscribe` bit should perform it's operations asynchronously. Apparently this is not the case.

Example:

```
ActiveSupport::Notifications.subscribe "some.channel" do |name, start, finish, id, payload|
  # do expensive task
  sleep(10)
end

ActiveSupport::Notifications.instrument "some.channel" #=> will return 10 seconds later
```

I was under the impression that `ActiveSupport::Notifications.instrument "some.channel"` would return right away and let the expensive task do expensive stuff. Otherwise I could just call the expensive task directly, without using a subscriber.

The documentation is also stating that there could be multiple subscribers. In that case I would get blocked until all other subscribers executed their code.

Is this right? If it is, can someone please explain what does this line from http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Notifications.html mean?

`The block will be called asynchronously whenever someone instruments “render”:`

Comment: This railscast might help you better understand what is going on http://railscasts.com/episodes/249-notifications-in-rails-3

Comment: I watched it several times. Ryan is not doing time consuming tasks in his subscriber so he didn't get the chance to mention that the use of `instrument` is blocking

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You're right. `ActiveSupport::Notifications.instrument` does not call the subscribers asynchronously / concurrently or anything of the sort.

If you follow the code, you'll find that `#instrument` calls an instrumenter, and instrumenter calls a notifier. The notifier is an instance of `ActiveSupport::Notifications::Fanout`, which sends notifications to all listeners via the [`#publish`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/f76dd271c6c6a3ae613a37c5a3b8b13b945b5d66/activesupport/lib/active_support/notifications/fanout.rb#L24-L26) method:

```
def publish(name, *args)
  listeners_for(name).each { |s| s.publish(name, *args) }
end
```

The [`#publish`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/f76dd271c6c6a3ae613a37c5a3b8b13b945b5d66/activesupport/lib/active_support/notifications/fanout.rb#L46-L48) method of the listener/subscriber is not asynchronous either:

```
def publish(message, *args)
  @delegate.call(message, *args)
end
```

All this does is call the block provided by the subscriber. Synchronously.

So why does the documentation claim that `The block will be called asynchronously whenever someone instruments “render”` and `Notifications ships with a queue implementation that consumes and publish events to log subscribers in a thread`?

It looks like the original implementation was asynchronous, and they forgot to update the documentation. If you look at the [change history for fanout.rb](https://github.com/rails/rails/commits/01c1127461c92be881b0a7278794ea759a0b8558/activesupport/lib/active_support/notifications/fanout.rb), you can see some commits from 2010 where the implementation was changed to a synchronous queue. A threaded implementation was probably too complicated and error-prone. You can even see some [vestiges](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/fe7e73086240a5bae4dc7cd01f8ec75ad8cddb96/activesupport/test/notifications_test.rb#L50) left over:

```
# This is a sync queue, so there is no waiting.
def wait
end
```

This looks like a good candidate for a commit to [docrails](https://github.com/lifo/docrails).

In any case, even if the implementation were asynchronous, you would probably want any long-running code to go into a queue (such as [resque](https://github.com/resque/resque)) and get processed by a background worker. This is so that your webapp worker processes aren't tied up processing long-running tasks, rather than serving requests.

**UPDATE**: Found a [commit](https://github.com/lifo/docrails/commit/c779a47d01ddcdcfde448c91b126fda1c935c9e9#activesupport/lib/active_support/notifications.rb) from 11 months ago that removes the incorrect information about notifications being asychronous. However, the incorrect information that the queue is running in a thread is still there.

**UPDATE 2**: I [committed](https://github.com/lifo/docrails/commit/e93e255161ee7836b6043a9ba286b6f23d0f9d8b) to docrails to fix the information about the queue running in a thread.

**UPDATE 3**: My commit has been merged into the official documentation.

Comment: This explains a lot. Thanks. I didn't get in such detail to find out that the documentation was outdated. I am already using sidekiq in my app and I'm considering doing that, but I need to figure stuff out first. Meanwhile I just put the code in the subscribe block in a `Thread.new {}` block. Very ugly but will get fixed asap.

Comment: A slight clarification: docrails doesn't take pull requests. Documentation PRs should go directly to rails/rails. The purpose of docrails is to give lots of contributors direct commit access to update the docs, and then periodically push those changes up the rails/rails.